# Erro em lista de estruturas em C

Tags: c, lista, struct, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Estou trabalhando em um código de lista de estruturas, onde tenho uma struct chamada cad que contém os campos matrícula, nome e salário. E uma lista contendo um campo do tipo struct cad que guarda os campos da struct cad em forma de lista. 
Portanto o código fica assim:

```
#define MAX 5

struct cad
{
    int mat;
    char nome[30];
    float sal;
};

struct lista
{
    int fim;
    struct cad memo[MAX];
};

typedef struct lista lista;
typedef struct cad cad;
int main()
{   lista l;
    cad x;
    int opc, pos;
    l.fim = -1;

do
{
    opc = menu();
    switch(opc)
    {
    case 1: //enfileirar
        if(l.fim==MAX-1)
            {
                printf("Lista Cheia ");
            } 
            else
            {
                printf("Matricula = ");
                scanf("%d", &x.mat);
                printf("Nome = ");
                fflush(stdin);
                gets(x.nome);
                printf("Salario = ");
                scanf("%f", &x.sal);
                inserir(&l, x);
            }
        break;

        case 2: //remover
            if(l.fim==-1)
            {
                printf("Lista vazia ");
            }
            else
            {
                x=remover(&l);
                printf("\n matricula = %d", x.mat);
                printf("\n nome = %s", x.nome);
                printf("\n salario = %f", x.sal);
            }
         break;
```

Porém ao criar uma função capaz de remover as informações em uma das posições de struct cad memo, me ocorre o erro de "incompatible types when assigning to type 'cad' from type 'int'|"

A função de remover ficou assim:

```
struct cad remover(lista *l)
{
    int i;
    struct cad aux;

    aux = l->memo[0];
    for(i=0;i<l->fim; i++)
    {
        l->memo[i] = l->memo[i+1];
    }
    l->fim--;
    return aux;
}
```

Alguém poderia me esclarecer o porque desse erro?

Comment: Sua estrutura não é uma lista ligada. Normalmente quando se chama "lista" se espera que seja um comportamento de lista ligada. Você apresentou um vetor com um índice limitante.

Comment: Sobre a questão, as funções estão declaradas antes da `main`? Se não estiverem, alguns compiladores C antigos assumem que o retorno é `int`

Comment: A propósito, não se use `float` para monetários: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/64969

Comment: Ola Esse é seu código completo, ou tem outra parte? Se tiver e puder postar acredito que ira auxiliar bastante a encontrar o erro. Porque tenho visto alguns erros aqui, você esta codificando uma lista sem ponteiros, será difícil seu código ficar correto. Se tiver mais código poste aqui, no caso você quer criar uma lista que contenha, matricula, nome e salário e fazer a inserção e remoção destas informações ?